# Why select multiple options disappears in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Really strange behavior, without multiple property the select works fine, with multiple the options disappear, you can test it here, with and without

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yezybn?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

```
            <select multiple>
                  <optgroup label="Properties">
                        <option *ngFor="let eachVal of notObjProp" value="{{eachVal.property}}">
                              <div>{{eachVal.property}}</div>
                        </option>
                  </optgroup>
                  <optgroup label="References to Properties">
                        <option *ngFor="let eachVal of objProp">
                              <div>{{eachVal.property}}</div>
                        </option>
                  </optgroup>
            </select>
```

Comment: Remove the `<div>` tags inside your `<option>` tags and things will work properly.

Comment: it works thank you, I haven't thought about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the HTML spec, [`<option>` elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#the-option-element) are allowed to contain text or be empty. If you remove the `<div>` tags inside of your `<option>` tags, the problem will be resolved.